# SQL connection (sybase driver) with python pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to connect to a database with python.

I'm not an expert in SQL, So I will put the parameters of my db

---

Driver = Sybase jConnect 6.0 (com.sybase.jdbc4.SybDriver)

URL = jdbc:sybase:Tds:slpdfrsiqq3401.fr.intranet:20301

Usename = myusername

Password = mypassword

Database = databasename

---

Since I don't have the right to install the package sybase-python, I'm trying to do the job with available packages. This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine=create_engine("jdbc+sybase://myusername:mypassword@slpdfrsiqq3401.fr.intranet:20301/databasename")

#Trying to creating engine to use then pd.read_sql_query()
```

My code doesn't work and I have this error :

"Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:jdbc.sybase"

Could anyone help me to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't see a point of using jdbc. I have not explored jdbc enough but not feel positive about the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try other drivers as suggested in the docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sybase.html)

Example

```
sybase+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>[/<database>]
```